# How to create a virtual serial port on mac

Tags: macos, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I want to create virtual serial port which can be used to communicate between two application. I had tried with pty/tty pair(pseudoterminal) on mac. It worked also. But what i need it i want to configure it in such a way that other application could find it while doing the serial port search. Here i am stuck.

Does anyone knows how to make this pair confiurable so that they can act as serial port and list down while doing a serial port search.

Comment: Did you find a solution?